# How can I stop a ListBox control from wrapping each item in a ListBoxItem?

Tags: wpf, listbox, canvas, wpf-controls, listboxitem

I am creating a timeline control that uses listbox to place my items on a canvas.
There are two parts to it. The base timeline to represent an 8 hour work day and the individual timeline elements which represent the type of work with start and end times.

The timeline element can be resized using a thumb control docked to the left and right of each element. The resizing works fine if I place the timline element on a canvas directly, but as I need to maintain a list of elements I thought that a listbox would handle it for me. So I made the ItemsPanel a canvas and sure enough everything rendered nicely. The only problem was that I could no longer resize the timeline elements. Quickly I relized, that setting the canvas.Left on my element when dragging would do nothing because the element was no longer on the canvas but inside a listboxitem (which is on the canvas).

Is it possible to have a Listbox stop wrapping each item in its own listboxitem and wrap them in say a custom ContentControl instead?

Comment: @Ilya: It must be. He's talking about a `Canvas`, so that's definitely not WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ContentControl();
    }
}
```

### Reference: [How to change the default item container for ItemsControl?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/F976B9E0-8B00-4144-89FB-BDA5FF0A7C7D)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by adding a `UIElement` directly to `ListBox.Items` (or `ItemsSource`). However, I'd recommend instead using `ItemContainerStyle` to change `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`. This style allows you to control properties on the container (the `ListBoxItem`) generated for each item in your `ItemsControl`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding SomeLeftProperty}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding SomeTopProperty}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have now and displays fine, the problem comes when I need to drag the thumb control on an timeline element to resize it. It cant work as the timeline element (which is a ContentControl) is not directly on the canvas. its wrapped up in the ListboxItem. I would need to apply the thumb control to the listboxitem instead for it to work.